# Marketing Cloud to Call login and logout URL - Journey Builder Customer Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

In my installed package I have a component which is a Marketing Cloud App that contains a login and logout url that is defined in my node.js app. How does marketing cloud call this login and logout, because I'm checking the logstream of my app and It doesn't seem to call this login and logout url.

in my app.js file it's defined as

```
app.get('/login', routing.login)
app.get('/logout', routing.logout)
```

in my installed packaged this is what my login and logout url looks like

```
login - https://websitename/login
logout - https://websitename/logout
```

Any tip or help will do thanks!